# Apache Flink (Error in stdout in cluster)

Tags: java, apache-flink

In `Apache Flink`, I am not able to see the output in `std out`, but my job is running successfully and data is coming

Comment: Are you running your job on YARN or standalone ? Please give us more information.

Comment: On standalone Cluster

Comment: Can you share with us your code, and errors if you get some.

Comment: Actually Error is not there , i am  not able to see output in stdout.. but i am able to see output in the workrs logs file

Comment: Update your post with your code, cause it's hard to help you without it.

Comment: i am upload my code as a answer..please check

Comment: Please find the detailed answer which I have provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62193641/7317816).

Answer (score 3):

As you are running your job on a cluster, DataStreams are printed to the stdout of the TaskManager process. This TaskManager stdout is directed to an .out file in the ./log/ directory of the Flink root directory. I believe this is here you have seen your output.

I don't know if it is possible to change the stdout of TaskManagers, however, a quick and dirty solution could be to write the output to a socket :

```
output.writeToSocket(outputHost, outputPort, new SimpleStringSchema())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // the host and the port to connect to
    final String hostname = "192.168.1.73";
    final int port = 9000;

    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment("192.168.1.68", 6123);

    // get input data by connecting to the socket
    DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream(hostname, port, "\n");

    // parse the data, group it, window it, and aggregate the counts
    DataStream<WordWithCount> windowCounts = text

            .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, WordWithCount>() {
                public void flatMap(String value, Collector<WordWithCount> out) {
                    for (String word : value.split("\\s")) {
                        out.collect(new WordWithCount(word, 1L));
                    }
                }
            })

            .keyBy("word").timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))

            .reduce(new ReduceFunction<WordWithCount>() {
                public WordWithCount reduce(WordWithCount a, WordWithCount b) {
                    return new WordWithCount(a.word, a.count + b.count);
                }
            });

    // print the results with a single thread, rather than in parallel
    windowCounts.print().setParallelism(1);

    env.execute("Socket Window WordCount");
}

public static class WordWithCount {

    public String word;
    public long count;

    public WordWithCount() {
    }

    public WordWithCount(String word, long count) {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word + " : " + count;
    }
}
```