# flink don't print the object in the std output

Tags: apache-flink

i'm doing a simple program in flink, but it doesn't print any string in the std output. I have tried both using a print() method on the stream and using a reduce function and after print() method on its result. this is a code:

public class StreamingJob {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.enableCheckpointing(10000);
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(200L);
    List<Oggetto> objects = produciValori();
    DataStream<Oggetto> stream = env.fromCollection(objects);
    stream./*
    timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(5)).reduce(new Reduce()).*/
    print();
    env.execute("Flink Streaming Java Quickstart Mio");
}

private static List<Oggetto> produciValori() {
    List<Oggetto> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    int prop1 = 0;
    int prop2 = 1000;
    String stringa1 = "stringa1: " + prop1;
    String stringa2 = "stringa2: " + prop2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        prop1 = prop1 + 1;
        prop2 = prop2 + 1;
        stringa1 = "stringa1: " + prop1;
        stringa2 = "stringa2: " + prop2;
        Oggetto o = new Oggetto(prop1, prop2, stringa1, stringa2);
        objects.add(o);
    }
    return objects;
}

private static class Reduce implements org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.ReduceFunction<Oggetto> {
    @Override
    public Oggetto reduce(Oggetto oggetto, Oggetto t1) throws Exception {
        if (oggetto.getPropInt1() <= t1.getPropInt1()){
            return oggetto;
        }else {
            return t1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

So whenever you use `println()` or `print()` to print the stream data/object, it actually prints on the console.

- When you execute code in local `IDE` it prints the stream data/object in `IDE console` but
- When you deploy the code as a `Flink Job` you can see the printed output in `.out` file in your Flink directory. In the below image you can see `flink-keshavlodhi-taskexecutor-0-Keshavs-MacBook-Pro.local.out` file.

You can find Flink log directory in your system where you have extracted the Flink tar file.
e.g

```
/Users/keshavlodhi/softwares/flink-1.10.0/log/
```

[image]

**Note:** Whenever you use any `logger` APIs to print that time you can find your stream data/object in `.log` files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting this job to a cluster, then you should find the output in the flink log directory in files with names like *-taskexecutor-*.out. If you are running in an IDE, the output should appear in the IDE's console.

Not having the Oggetto class available, I just replaced it with something simple, and was able to run your application just fine.

Comment: i'm submitting with: ./bin/flink run <name>.jar. in this file there is a this warming, why?  WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment (file:/home/giuseppe/Tesi/flink-1.7.2-bin-scala_2.11/flink-1.7.2/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.7.2.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations